# JAVA Linked List :method to insertLast

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

I have my code as following:

```
Node current=head;
if(current==null)//check 
else{
    while(current.getNext()!=null)
    current=current.getNext(); //loop through to find the last node in the list
}
//if I find it then connect it with my newNode(add) 
Node add=new Node("A");
current.setLink(add);
add.setLink(null);
```

But it does not work, I drawn a diagram but still have no idea what`s wrong with it.

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: If current == head == null, I imagine you're getting a null reference exception...

Comment: I try to insert an element at the end of this list

Answer (score 0):

the line

if(current==null) //why do you check if you don't have any statements afterwards?

this solution is for singly linked list:

```
public static Node addLast(Node head, Object x) {
       // save the reference to the header so we can return it.
       Node ret = head;

       // check base case, head is null.
       if (header == null) {
           return new Node(x, null);
       }

       // loop until we find the end of the list
       while ((head.next != null)) {
           head = head.next;
       }

       // set the new node to the Object x, next will be null.
       head.next = new Node(x, null);
       return ret;
   }
```